Proper way to use task in SwiftUI
I have recently started using SwiftUI and have build up a simple app that fetches data from a web service. I have following code in my View
    struct ProductsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: ProductViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(content: {
                ForEach(viewModel.products, id: \.self) { product in
                    ProductRow(product: product)
                }
            })
            .padding()
        }
        .task {
            try? await viewModel.fetchProducts()
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.showError) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text($viewModel.productError.wrappedValue?.localizedDescription ?? ""), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}

main app file:
    @main
struct WayfairTestProjectApp: App {
    @StateObject var productsProvider = ProductViewModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ProductsView()
                .environmentObject(productsProvider)
        }
    }
}

ViewModel:
@MainActor
class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var products: [Product] = []
    @Published var showError = false
    @Published var productError: ProductError?
    
    private let provider: ProductProvider

    init(provider: ProductProvider = ProductProvider()) {
        self.provider = provider
    }
    
    func fetchProducts() async throws {
        do {
            self.products = try await provider.products
        }
        catch let error as ProductError {
            productError = error
            showError = true
        }
    }

}

Provider:
final class ProductProvider {
    
    private let productsURL = URL(string: "https://api.wayfair.io/interview-sandbox/android/json-to-list/products.v1.json")!
    
    private lazy var decoder: JSONDecoder = {
        let aDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        aDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
        return aDecoder
    }()

    private let downloader: any HTTPDataDownloader
    
    var products: [Product] {
        get async throws {
            let data = try await downloader.httpData(from: productsURL)
            let products = try decoder.decode([Product].self, from: data)
            return products
        }
    }
    
    init(downloader: any HTTPDataDownloader = URLSession.shared) {
        self.downloader = downloader
    }
}

The app works fine but When I run above code with debugger the viewModel.fetchProducts() is called three times which is surprising as I have only used it once. Can someone please suggest how can I improve it?

Are you sure fetchProducts() is called 3 times from this task ? After all your viewModel comes from the environment and without seeing more code it's hard to say.

yes I checked with debugger, it is called three times, I have now added code from main file and also from ViewModel

Could not replicate your issue, all works well for me in my tests,
the .task {...} is only called once.
On MacOS 14.5, using Xcode 15.4, tested on real ios 17 devices and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.
Note, NavigationView is deprecated, use NavigationStack instead.

Generally, when you are using a "View Model" from the MVVM pattern, don't pass it through the SwiftUI environment. In MVVM a view model has a 1:1 relationship with the view - including its lifetime, i.e. there is one view model object for one view object and both have the same lifetime. When putting the view model into the environment its lifetime is not bound to the view anymore. If it's not a view model (and the way it's implemented suggests this), but a "data provider" or something else, you might use the environment, but then don't name it "ViewModel". :)

I can't reproduce it myself. Just to clarify again: when you run this code in a minimal example, does it expose the same faulty behaviour? The task modifier should run once, and only once when the underlying view object (managed by SwiftUI) will be created. In your complete production app, chances are, that this view will be created more often than you expect which then causes the observed behaviour.

When you use async/await you can remove the old Combine ObservableObject class since .task already provides the required reference semantics. Also, your async funcs need to return  results. It should look something like this:
struct ProductsView: View {
    @Environment(\.productController) var controller

    enum Result {
        case .success([Product])
        case .failure(Error)
    }

    @State var result: Result?

    var body: some View {
       ...
       .task { // starts on appear and cancels on disappear (similar to how the old @StateObject was init on appear and deinit on disappear).
           do {
               result = nil
               let products = try await controller.fetchProducts()
               result = .success(products)
           }
           catch {
               result = .failure(error)
           }
       }
    }
}



struct ProductController {
    func fetchProducts() async throws -> [Product] {
        ...

In your previews you can replace the controller in the environment with a mock that returns sample data.
You can use a computed property to transform [Product] as it is passed into child View inits. In child Views you can use .task(id: product.id) to fetch additional info.

This is a strange behavior which happened to me multiple times, mostly when using List in the View (it was running twice for me). I was not always able to reproduce it in a clean project, but in some projects of mine it happens consistently. Some people like me might argue that this is a bug of the SDK. For reference see This thread at Apple or this one at StackOverflow.
